# ValueError (In python, using JSON as input for dictConfig API)

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, logging

I am using the dictConfig API (logging.config) on python 2.7 and JSON as the input for default configurations. 
Could anyone help me with this?
This is the code which I run:

```
with open("config.json","r") as fconfigObj:
    defaultConfigs = json.load(fconfigObj)
logger1 = logging.getLogger('A.py')
logging.config.dictConfig(defaultConfigs)
```

The traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "alpha.py", line 123, in <module>
    logging.config.dictConfig(defaultConfigs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 794, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 576, in configure
    '%r: %s' % (name, e))
ValueError: Unable to configure handler u'loggers': 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

The config.JSON file:

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "disable_existing_loggers": "False",
  "formatters": {
    "standard": {
      "format": "%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(name)s: %(message)s"
    }
  },
  "handlers": {
    "default": {
      "level": "INFO",
      "formatter": "standard",
      "class": "logging.FileHandler",
      "filename": "abc.log"
    },
    "loggers": {
      "": {
        "handlers": "['default']",
        "propagate": "True",
        "level": "INFO"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe `"handlers": "['default']",` should be `"handlers": ['default'],` instead.  Also I'm used to seeing the actual boolean values `True` and `False` instead of the strings `"True"` and `"False"`.

Comment: @JohnGordon If that's the case, it should be `["default"]`, since JSON strings need to be double-quoted.

Comment: @glibdud You're right; I was looking at the `settings.py` file from an application of mine, which is not JSON.

Comment: @JohnGordon thanks, true/false changes and changing to ["default"] also helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That JSON file has `"loggers"` as a subitem underneath `"handlers"`, but those two items should be at the same level.